# Writing efficient code and optimizing memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, coding-style

I have these two snippets of code (written in Java) which is more more efficient?

```
int foo(){

   int result;
   for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
      SomeObject a,b,c;
      a = new SomeObject();
      b = new SomeObject();
      c = new SomeObject();
      //do something with a,b,c
      //and derive result
   }
   return result;
}
```

or

```
int foo(){

   int result;
   SomeObject a,b,c;
   a = new SomeObject();
   b = new SomeObject();
   c = new SomeObject();

   for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
      a.flush(); //reset object do not create new though
      b.flush(); //reset object do not create new though
      c.flush(); //reset object do not create new though
      //do something with a,b,c
      //and derive result
   }
   return result;
}
```

In the second snippet, I have moved the local variables out of the loop, so effectively it creates only one instance of them. Does this improve anything?
Logically, it would make sense when the variables are inside the loop. But would the garbage collector clean up the objects efficiently?

EDIT: Updated the snipped, regarding instantiation of objects.

Comment: Isn't this a case where the edit rendered all the answers invalid?  Go wiki-spirit, go!  Seen how great it works, where basically hardly anyone edits questions and the only edits are actually changing the question... Ah SO, can't wait for the next big thing because this is becoming a comedy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've moved the *variables* out, but those aren't *objects*. Assuming you're assigning different values to `a`, `b` and `c` on every iteration of the loop, you haven't reduced memory allocation at all - you've just widened the scope of variables unnecessarily.

If you don't need to change the values of `a`, `b` and `c` in the loop then that's a different matter, and it would be a better idea to assign them outside the loop rather than on every iteration.

The main thing is to realize the difference between *objects* and *variables* though. In particular, creating "new" variables on each iteration of the loop doesn't actually cost anything.

EDIT: Okay, with the updated question, there clearly *is* a difference in terms of how many objects are created. However, depending on exactly what's going on the second form may still be more preferable: it's certainly easier to understand, and it doesn't rely on the details of what the `flush` operation does. On the other hand, if creating an instance of `SomeObject` is expensive (e.g. it generates crypto keys) then it's a good idea to optimize against that.

In short: it depends. Write the most readable code first, measure it, and compare that with your performance requirements. Only move to less obvious code when there's a demonstrable benefit.

Comment: Updated the question. Somehow I missed out the initialization part.

Answer (score 3):

As written, they're the same.  In both cases the memory for the SomeObject references is allocated in the function's stack frame, once when function begins executing.

Therefore, prefer the version with the most limited scope.  That will have another advantage too - if your function were to go one and do something that took some time after the loop, the SomeObject instances would be eligible for GC immediately the loop ends.

But note, there would be a material difference if one or more of the objects is initialized with a `new` ***and*** the object constructed is the same on every loop iteration ***and*** it's reusable.  Then it would be far better to avoid needlessly creating and discarding the same object on every loop iteration.

#### Edit for Updated Question

FWIW, I disagree with Jon Skeet on this detail: Given the updated question, it will always be preferable to construct the objects outside the loop and reuse them on each iteration. If the other code in the method is so complex as to make that undesirable, then it's the method, not the loop, that needs refactoring.

Comment: But the number of instances of `SomeObject` created in the second version in n compared to 1 in the first version. Would that matter?

Comment: @Codevalley: My original answer already addresses that (see "But note...").  I have updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection does clean up object efficiently, however that doesn't mean it is zero cost.  What you have to consider in the second example is that you have to have mutable objects which can be reset() back to their original state, which again is not at zero cost.

The answer for most performance questions is; write the code as clear and as simple as you can and the result will also have good performance which is usually enough.  If you do have a performance problem, profile your application to see what might need to change.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually tested this, and there is no difference because the compiler figures out that option 1 is can be done better as option 2 and changes it to that anyway.

Code for clarity first, efficiency second (the compiler is smarter than you anyway)

Comment: Now that the question has changed, I don't think this answer is valid. In particular a different number of `SomeObject` objects *are* created.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if they are getting constructed each loop iteration in both instances, then neither is more efficient.  If you initialize them outside the loop body then the latter one would be faster.